# Trouble starting Random Walker java program at 0,0 coordinates

Tags: java

I am trying to build a program that takes an integer and simulates the motion of a random walk until the random walker is at Manhattan distance r from the starting point. One of the key requirements is to start the program at 0,0 coordinates but I am unable

```
public class RandomWalker {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int step = 0;
        double R;
        while(Math.abs(x) < r && Math.abs(y) < r) {
            step++;
            R = Math.random();
            if(R <= 0.25) x++;
            else if (R <= 0.50) x--;
            else if (R <= 0.75) y++;
            else if (R <= 1.00) y--;

            System.out.println("(" + x + ", " + y + ")" );
        }
        System.out.println("steps = " + step);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be starting at (0,0). Why do you think it's not? I note, however, that you have not implements manhattan distance correctly. The test should be `Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y) < r`.

Comment: When I run tests it never starts at (0,0). Also the autograder for the course suggested that the coordinates aren't at (0,0). I don't get it though. If x and y are initialized to 0, shouldn't they always start at 0?

Comment: I suspect it's just because you're printing the coordinates after changing them. Print first and you'll see it's 0,0 to start with. I'll add an answer.

Comment: Do you mean you're supposed to be *printing* that the walk starts at 0,0?

Comment: Oh my word.. that's embarrassing. Makes sense now- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you just need to print the coordinates before stepping. See below. I've also tried to encapsulate the walker values in the class rather than the main method.

```
public class RandomWalker {
    private final Random random;
    private int steps = 0;
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    public RandomWalker(Random random) {
        this.random = random;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return steps + ": (" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }

    public void step() {
        steps++;
        switch (random.nextInt(4)) {
            case 0: x++; break;
            case 1: x--; break;
            case 2: y++; break;
            case 3: y--; break;
        }
    }

    public int distance() {
        return Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        RandomWalker walker = new RandomWalker(new Random());
        while (walker.distance() < r) {
            System.out.println(walker);
            walker.step();
        }
        System.out.println("steps = " + walker.steps);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you print the `(x,y)` first, before the circle. Then you will get an `(0,0)` and the condition should be `<r`, iso `<=r`, otherwise the steps will count 1+ time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above is pretty good but this is an exam from the `WEEK2` Princeton course
*Computer Science: Programming with a Purpose* and they only use Java features that have already been introduced in the course (e.g., loops and conditionals, but not arrays or functions).

Here is a solution that is acceptable:

```
public class RandomWalker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int distance = 0;
        int steps = 0;
        System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
        while (distance < r) {
            double i = Math.random();
            if (i < 0.25) {
                y = y + 1;
                System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                distance = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y);
                steps += 1;
            }
            if (i < 0.5) {
                x = x + 1;
                System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                distance = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y);
                steps += 1;
            }
            if (i < 0.75) {
                y = y - 1;
                System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                distance = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y);
                steps += 1;
            }
            if (i >= 0.75 && i < 1) {
                x = x - 1;
                System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                distance = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y);
                steps += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Steps = " + steps);
    }
}
```